# Detect URL changes in Webview android

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using android webview and loading an url. Inside the webview, there are certain click events and on clicking , the UI inside webview is changed. I am not getting any callback in **shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...)**. Is there a way to detect the changes inside webview in android?

The **shouldOverrideUrlLoading()** is called only when baseUrl changes.

Comment: Please check this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-can-i-get-onclick-event-on-webview-in-android

Comment: Thank you Rafiq, But that was not a reliable way to implement the requirement. I have an Url like "xxxxx/dasboard", which changes to "xxxxx/feedback" on clicking. I have tried to detect Url change using the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312499/android-detect-webview-url-change but did not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)** method is called when every url changes and loads. The Url can be parsed to find out the change.

Comment: Single page applications do not provide callbacks for every URL change. Hence need to check the "onProgressChanged(Webview view, int progress)" in WebChromeClient to get all URL changes.