# Run layout by link in web view

Tags: android, webview, urlparse

I have to make an improvement to my webview application. But I couldn't figure out how or where to do it. I'm kind of a novice about android also i want to remove ads from webview.

Here's exactly what I want

When the user navigating within the app opens the link to "

> https://www.xxxxxx.com/m/messages.php?display=one_chat&user_id=180045

I want the ad-free layout to load.

I'd appreciate it if you'd explain it with a small sample.

Comment: listen to URL changes in `WebView` and check which URL user navigated to.

Comment: how do i do it ? Can you show any examples?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android detect webview URL change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312499/android-detect-webview-url-change)

Comment: Now I was looking at this. I'il test it now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, the solution was quite easy.

//Show loader on url load
            public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {

```
            if (!datingView.getUrl().contains("messages.php") || !datingView.getUrl().contains("messages.php" +
                    "")){
                bannerAds.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                bannerAds.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            // if url contains string androidexample
            // Then show progress  Dialog
            if (progressDialog == null && url.contains("instasquare")
                    ) {

                // in standard case YourActivity.this
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(appMain.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }
```